# Forgot password php prevent too many emails being sent

Tags: php, authentication, forgot-password

Currently my users can repeatedly send emails using forgot password link. How can I prevent people from spamming it. I already have a recaptcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas :

- First, make sure the email address exists in your database, to prevent your application from spamming people who don't have an account on your site
- Second, don't allow more than 1 or 2 mail per day to be sent to each email address.

  - Or don't allow more than 2-3 mails sent to an e-mail address ; and reset the counter when the password is changed by the user.

Comment: Just one side note: don't respond by saying whether or not the account linked to a certain email address exists; this way, it's very easy to check if someone has an account at your site (people might not like that, especially if you host some XXX forum).

Comment: @Marcel: The problem with not doing so is that there's no confirmation for a genuine user as to whether they've typed their email address correctly.

Comment: @Oli: hmmm, people can *read* (or use a screen reader) before they press the submit button, can't they? And if they don't receive a notification within, say, 10 minutes, they can just retry. I really, really hate it when someone can just check my paths by testing whether or not I have an account at some forum, etc. (and no, I don't have an account at some XXX rated forum, in case someone wonders; I'm just keen on my privacy).

Comment: Do you need a confirmation?  Not getting the email is a good indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Each email can request up to X times per day.
Store each email request count in the DB (I assume you send only to emails registered in your DB).
Also, do not reset password until user actually presses the link in his email.